# Escaping problems with HTMLParser [Python]

Tags: python, escaping, html-parsing

I'm using `HTMLParser` to parse a xhtml file. I'm interested in getting the data within the CodeSnippet tags. I'm using `handle_data` to get that info but when there is `&#160;` it breaks the data string and I only get `HRESULT get_Top(` instead of getting the entire content within the `CodeSnippet` tags.
Here you can see the code I'm trying to get info from.

```
<CodeSnippet runat="server" Language="ManagedCPlusPlus" DisplayLanguage="C++" xmlns="http://msdn2.microsoft.com/mtps">
HRESULT get_Top(
  [out]&#160;long *pTop
);

</CodeSnippet>
```

This is the code I have:

```
class LinksParser(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.recording = False
    self.data = []

    self.categories=[]

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attributes):
    if tag == 'codesnippet':
        self.recording = True

  def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.recording:
      print data
      self.recording=False
```

How can I do it so I get all the content from the tag?

Cheers

Comment: Please show the code you already have.

Comment: @KlausD. I just did it. Cheers